# Suddenly can not connect to other PC's FMS after 1 month?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, flash-media-server, fms3

Previously, we can use FMS to do livestream video chatting via 2 swf files. 
After we have implemented a bit and retest with my friend and try to connect again. we only can connect to our own FMS, But can not connect to other IP (FMS) .

Is there any limitation for Free version of FMS ?

Comment: Is FMS A Flying Model simulator? i googled thats all i seemed to get anyway i think your answer could be found at there website.Or give more info cause i dont think it really flash related as the flash files are published so you wouldnt have accesss to the code legally

Answer (score 0):

The free (development) version of Flash media server is limited to 10 simultaneous connections.  There is no time limit or other restrictions.